# How to raise exception from command run by xp_cmdshell?

Tags: sql-server

The following code uses xp_cmdshell to execute bcp.exe. However, it continues to run the following code even if the command/executable failed. How to raise an exception if the execution (my special case is running sybase bcp) didn't succeeded?

```
declare @cmd varchar(max) = 'c:\sybase\bcp.exe ....'
begin try
  exec xp_cmdshell @cmd
  // .... do something if there is no error when executing @cmd
  // Otherwise, STOP!
end try
begin catch
  // report error
end catch
```

Answer (score 2):

Below is an example from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175046.aspx) that might help...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

xp_cmdshell will (if the invoked program cooperates) return either a 0 if the program ended successfully or Null if not. I don't think try catch will be affected either way.